# Java: Longest Island in a matrix

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to execute a code which returns the max length of island of 1's in a  matrix of 1's and 0's.

In a matrix of 1's and 0's, if two adjacent elements of the matrix are 1's, then they can form an island. A matrix can have multiple islands. Adjacent elements can be horizontal,vertical or diagonal.

Here is the logic:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class IslandMatrix {


    static final int ROW = 5, COL = 5;
    static int max_1 = 0;
    public boolean isSafe(int M[][], int row, int col,
                   boolean visited[][])
    {
        if( (row >= 0) && (row < ROW) &&
               (col >= 0) && (col < COL) &&
               (M[row][col]==1 && !visited[row][col])){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    int DFS(int M[][], int row, int col, boolean visited[][])
    {
        max_1 = max_1+1;
        int rowNbr[] = new int[] {-1,  0,  1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1};
        int colNbr[] = new int[] {-1, -1, -1,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1};
        visited[row][col] = true;
        for (int k = 0; k < 8; ++k)
            if (isSafe(M, row + rowNbr[k], col + colNbr[k], visited)){
                DFS(M, row + rowNbr[k], col + colNbr[k], visited);
            }
        return max_1;
    }

    int countIsland(int M[][])
    {
        boolean visited[][] = new boolean[ROW][COL];
        //int count = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        int max =0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < COL; ++j){
                max_1 = 0;
                if (M[i][j]==1 && !visited[i][j]){
                    temp =  DFS(M, i, j, visited);
                    if(temp>max){
                        max = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        return max;
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int M[][]=  new int[][] {{0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
                                 {0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                                 {1, 0, 1, 1, 0},
                                 {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                                 {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}
                                };
     IslandMatrix I = new IslandMatrix();
     System.out.println("Max length of island is: "+ I.countIsland(M));
    }
}
```

Consider:

```
 {0, 1, 0, 1, 0}
 {0, 0, 1, 1, 1}
 {1, 0, 1, 1, 0}
 {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
 {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}
```

In this case the longest island with 1's is following the index path as below:
(0,1)->(1,2)->(1,3)->(0,2)->(1,4)->(2,3)->(2,2)->(3,1)->(2,0)

in this way the result should be 9 but i am getting the result as 10.

Can anyone help me out with the proper logic.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be 10? I have counted 10. (0,1),(0,3),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4), (2,0),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(4,2)

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: Have you checked [this example of the algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736983/count-islands-of-zeros-in-a-matrix?rq=1)

Comment: Yes it would be 10 but i was considering a situation like the length of 1s. Then the case would be like traversing in one direction from a point.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are using DFS. 
It will find all connected point not a longest path. 
The result is 10 because we have a backward in point(3,1).
For exam if you change point(1,0) to 1 the result is 11.

This is main problem. Resolve it the code will work.
If you can't I will help you.

Comment: Yeah even i see that the code is back tracking. How can I avoid this? Can you give me a logic for this?